# SonarQube: Have 'Alerts' been replaced by 'Quality Gates'?

Tags: sonarqube

:D

I am reading the *SonarQube in Action* book by Campbell and Papapetrou and am reading Chapter 13 where the authors describe Alerts. This is on page 252 of the book if you have a copy. What they are describing is not on SonarQube 4.5.X though. It seems like these alerts have been replaced by 'Quality Gates'. Is this the case? Or am I missing something?

Thank-you for reading this. :)

Respectfully,

user3870315

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you're not missing anything. Alerts have definitely been replaced by Quality Gates.

Hope you're enjoying the book! :)